Comparison between "in which", "by which" and relavent items
"In the car" and "by a car" are often used interchangeably：
I went there in a car.
I went there by car
Then which of the counterparts, "by which" and "in which", to these to constructions will work in a relative clause:

This is the car in which I went to London.
1a. This is the car which I went to London in.

This is the car by which I went to London.

They built ships in which to escape.

They built ships by which to escape.

They built ships with which to escape.

They built ships to escape.

They built ships to escape in.


I'm guessing 1, 3, 6. With the preposition put ar the end, 1a is disfavoured.

No, you are mistaken. 1a is fine.

By as in by car, by train, by sea, by air refers to the mode of transport rather than the individual vehicle, so (2) and (4) don't sound right.
It is traditionally considered wrong to put the preposition at the end, but that rule is now considered old-fashioned. See this question.
